# Add coordinates after click into form

Tags: leaflet, php

I would like to add the coordinates as a click to the map as a form entry, I do not know how the function structure should look like

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
    var lat = e.latlng.lat;
});

<input type="text" name="coordy" value=" <script type="text/javascript">  document.write(lat) </script> ">
```

It is not working.

Answer (score 5):

Create your `<input>` with an unique [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), so then later you can get a reference to it via [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

```
<input type="text" id="coordy" />
```

There is no need to include a `value` attribute in this `<input>`, as the `value` will be overwritten later. See the [documentation for the `<input>` HTML tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) about its `value` attribute. Note that the `value` attribute is **not** javascript.

In your Leaflet event handler: Get a reference to the [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) that corresponds to your `<input>` HTML tag, and then set the `value` property of that `HTMLInputElement`.

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
  var lat = e.latlng.lat;
  document.getElementById('coordy').value = lat;
});
```